# Converted this code from C# to Java, is there anything else that can be simplified in Java?

Tags: java, c#, algorithm

This is a function that, given an array A consisting of N integers, where A[K] denotes the height of the K-th tree, returns the number of ways of cutting out one tree, so that the remaining trees are aesthetically pleasing. If it is not possible to achieve the desired result, the function should return -1. If it's already aesthetically pleasing without any removal, the function should return 0.

This is the code written in **C#**.

```
using System;

namespace activity_problem
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
    }

    class Solution
    {
        public int solution(int[] a)
        {
            if (isAesthetic(a))
            {
                return 0;
            }

            int aestheticPatternCount = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < a.Length; j++)
            {
                int[] newA = copyArrayWithoutAnElement(a, j);
                if (isAesthetic(newA))
                {
                    aestheticPatternCount++;
                }
            }

            if (aestheticPatternCount == 0)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else
            {
                return aestheticPatternCount;
            }
        }

        private int[] copyArrayWithoutAnElement(int[] array, int indexOfElementToBeRemoved)
        {
            int arrayLength = array.Length;
            int[] newArr = new int[arrayLength - 1];
            int tempK = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < arrayLength; k++)
            {
                if (k != indexOfElementToBeRemoved)
                {
                    newArr[tempK++] = array[k];
                }
            }
            return newArr;
        }

        private Boolean isAesthetic(int[] array)
        {
            int newArrayLength = array.Length;
            int increasingFlag = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < newArrayLength; i++)
            {
                if (increasingFlag == 0)
                {
                    if (array[i] < array[i + 1])
                    {
                        increasingFlag = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        increasingFlag = 2;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (increasingFlag == 1)
                    {
                        if (i % 2 == 1 && array[i] > array[i - 1])
                        {

                        }
                        else if (i % 2 == 0 && array[i] < array[i - 1])
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (i % 2 == 1 && array[i] < array[i - 1])
                        {

                        }
                        else if (i % 2 == 0 && array[i] > array[i - 1])
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Converted into **JAVA**, is there anything else that could be possibly simplified?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            Solution sol = new Solution();
            int solution = sol.solution(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
            System.out.println(solution);
        }

        public static class Solution {
            public int solution(int[] a){
                if (isAesthetic(a))
                {
                    return 0;
                }
                int aestheticPatternCount = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++)
                {
                    int[] newA = copyArrayWithoutAnElement(a, j);
                    if (isAesthetic(newA))
                    {
                        aestheticPatternCount++;
                    }
                }
                if (aestheticPatternCount == 0)
                {
                    return -1;
                }
                else
                {
                    return aestheticPatternCount;
                }
            }
            private int[] copyArrayWithoutAnElement(int[] array, int indexOfElementToBeRemoved)
            {
                int arrayLength = array.length;
                int[] newArr = new int[arrayLength - 1];
                int tempK = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < arrayLength; k++)
                {
                    if (k != indexOfElementToBeRemoved)
                    {
                        newArr[tempK++] = array[k];
                    }
                }
                return newArr;
            }
            private Boolean isAesthetic(int[] array)
            {
                int newArrayLength = array.length;
                int increasingFlag = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < newArrayLength; i++)
                {
                    if (increasingFlag == 0)
                    {
                        if (array[i] < array[i + 1])
                        {
                            increasingFlag = 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            increasingFlag = 2;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (increasingFlag == 1)
                        {
                            if (i % 2 == 1 && array[i] > array[i - 1])
                            {
                            }
                            else if (i % 2 == 0 && array[i] < array[i - 1])
                            {
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (i % 2 == 1 && array[i] < array[i - 1])
                            {
                            }
                            else if (i % 2 == 0 && array[i] > array[i - 1])
                            {
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm currently trying to learn algorithm in Java so any help or input is really appreciated.

Comment: You're creating a lot of arrays and comparing neighbour elements multiple times. I'd start by flipping the solution to perform all the required comparisons just once, without mutating the source data at all.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman uh, could you please elaborate? I'm really newbie into Java. 

Comment: It's already the C# code actually, that is pretty bad as an example. Looks a bit like this has been converted from C previously.

Answer (score 0):

For readability:

One thing you can do to simplify the code is remove the empty else-if branches.

Another would be to follow the usual [java conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-contents.html) and have the curly braces on the same line, for example:

```
if (something) {
    // ...
} else if (somethingElse) {
    // ...
} else {
    // ...
}
```

For the actual program logic:

Instead of looking to port the code exactly as it is written, you can simplify some parts of it by using the Collections api. For example, if you *need* an array (and not some kind of List) then you can do all the work with removing elements, etc with a collection (e.g. `ArrayList`) and convert it to an array at the end.

Also, as noted in the comments there is a lot of comparison going on. If you can simplify that and do less comparing you'll have a better algorithm.

I would suggest starting with some unit tests with cases to validate against both the old code and new code.